# Favicon not seen in Flask app

Tags: python, flask, favicon

The favicon is currently not being displayed on pages served by my Flask app. I have the following two routes, how do I ensure the favicon is displayed?

```
@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return redirect("tg://resolve?domain=sneakersale", code=302)

@app.route('/favicon.ico')
def fav():
    return send_from_directory(os.path.join(app.root_path, 'static'),'favicon.ico')
```

Comment: Are you sure that `favicon.ico` is getting called in the first place? I'd try placing a debug-print statement there, and trying to ping it with a web browser - maybe use the dev console of the browser, as well, to figure out the root of the problem.

Comment: No, not in the first place, I guess. But how to put it in order on the first place?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the following `<link>` tag to specify your favicon within your jinja2 templates. Ensure `href` is set to the URL rule that you wrote in your question (`/favicon.ico`)

```
<head>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico">
</head>
```

Comment: This really helped me out with Chrome! But doesn't work in Safari :(

Comment: Then, the issue is with Safari and displaying favicons within HTML (and which tag/attributes to use), not with Flask.

Comment: And if I added icons in href, then in which folder do I put them? Now they are located in templates/ folder

Comment: From your original post, I can see that you've placed `favicon.ico` inside of `/static/`, correct? If so, the `href` attribute should look like `href={{ url_for("static", filename="favicon.ico") }}`.

Comment: now it works, but on social net page favicon is only dislpayed if i put bla.bla/static. because now I can get favicon directly only by bla.bla/static/favicon.ico

Answer (score 3):

If you're copying and pasting in the @Sean Pianka example, you might consider adding a double-quote to your href, and to differentiate, perhaps use single-quotes for items inside, like `href="{{ url_for('static', filename='favicon.ico') }}"`.  While href allows for unquoted values, for me, this string failed without them.